# using "where" keyword to limit the generic candidates to be a class, which is also a generic

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a series

```
public class TimeSeries<T,K>
```

and I want to construct a class which has a list member that can store `TimeSeries` as element, so I use:

```
public class TimeSeriesSet<M> where M: TimeSeries<T, K>
```

I wonder what would be the correct syntax for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class TimeSeriesSet<T, K>
{
  public TimeSeries<T, K> SomeField;
}
```

No need to use constraints at all. Don't use generic type arguments if you're not actually going to use them ;)

The only reason why you'd want to add *another* type argument would be if you wanted some explicit descendant of `TimeSeries<T, K>`. In that case, just add it as yet another type argument:

```
public class TimeSeriesSet<M, T, K>
  where M: TimeSeries<T, K>
{
  public M SomeField;
}
```

In general, genericity tends to propagate. If you need something generic over something generic, you need two generic type arguments. Thankfully, type inference usually works. Usually.

Answer (score 1):

Luaan's answer covers two of the ways to structure your code.  However, there is a variation that you could use.  It looks as though TimeSeriesSet is one way coupled to TimeSeries both in name and via the type parameters.  I wonder if perhaps, one of the following wouldn't make more sense in your application:

Without the descendant constraint:

```
public class TimeSeries<T, K>
{
    public class Set
    {
        public TimeSeries<T, K> SomeField;
    }
}
```

Or with the descendant constraint:

```
public class TimeSeries<T, K>
{
    public class Set<M> where M : TimeSeries<T, K>
    {
        public M SomeField;
    }
}
```

This has the added advantage of DRYing up the type parameter declarations and more clearly models that `TimeSeriesSet<T, K, M>` is dependent on `TimeSeries<T, K>` and its type parameters by making it `TimeSeries<T, K>.Set<M>`.